# Is it possible to make a variable go down/up every second?

Tags: batch-file, windows-8

I'm making an RPG Game with Windows BATCH and blood is a variable. I wanted to add bleeding, but don't really know how to do this.

Are there any changes I can make to make *%blood%* go down every second?

```
:BLEEDINGHUNGERANDTHIRST  
if /a %bleeding% equ 1 set %blood% = 5500 -=1
```

(I know, it's wrong)

Comment: `if /a` isn't valid syntax, and also `set %blood% = 5500 -= 1` is absolutly wrong

Comment: Batch is a lousy platform for developing a game of any complexity, but it can be an interesting challenge. Any RPG worth playing is an inherently complex program requiring a lot of careful planning. Doing this with batch makes the task even harder, requiring loads of arcane knowledge and lots of dicipline. A real-time RPG in batch is theoretically possible, but from a practical standpoint I think you should not attempt it. If you insist on developing an RPG with batch, then I strongly suggest you do a turn based game instead of real-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumming `bleeding` is 0 (no bleeding) or 1 (bleeding), more (gore) or less (healing)

```
set /a "blood-=bleeding"
```

To make it happen every second depends of the rest of the code and when and how you call your routines.

A dirty way could be

```dos
:BLEEDINGHUNGERANDTHIRST    
if not %bleeding%==0 for /f "tokens=3 delims=:,. " %%a in ("%time::0=:%") do (
    if not defined lastBleedingTime ( 
        set "lastBleedingTime=%%a"
        set /a "blood-=%bleeding%"
    ) else (
        if not %lastBleedingTime%0==%%a0 (
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            if !lastBleedingTime! gtr %%a (
                set /a "gap=60-lastBleedingTime+%%a"
            ) else (
                set /a "gap=%%a-lastBleedingTime"
            )
            for /f %%b in ("!gap!") do (
                endlocal 
                set /a "lastBleedingTime=%%a", "blood-=%bleeding%*%%b"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

This uses the difference in time between the last call and now. The bleeding is substracted from the bood counter depending on the seconds elapsed from the last check. For this to work, you need to ensure you call the routine more than once in an minute (ideally at least each second) and to use `set "lastBleedingTime="` when the player stops bleeding.

Comment: Nice, but then there will be the small problems with user inputs

Comment: @jeb, `choice` with a timeout and a default hidden option? a second thread?, ... i don't know how the OP code works or what it requests from the user. This sample just does the basic calcs. I don't have the needed knowledge of the problem. Anyway, good point.

Comment: @MCND I didn't know how to actually make it go down in real time, and I guess that's what I wanted it to do. It wouldn't really request input, just kind of go down without the user doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, but you need some knowlegde about advanced batch programming.

You simply start two threads.
One thread is for waiting and accepting user input, the second thread is for calculating such things like bleeding.

For synchronization you should look at the technic from dbenham.
See a reference game [SNAKE.BAT An arcade style game using pure batch](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4741)

Comment: uh - that is hard stuff for someone who already fails at `set` ^^

Comment: @Stephan Yes, indeed. Therefore I mention the part `you need some knowlegde` :-)

Comment: @Stephan I fail at pretty much everything in this language, have no idea why I'm trying to make an RPG with it. Everything else seems to work though... weird